# is it possible to install joomla 2.5 on a server with mysql version 4.x.x?

Tags: mysql, joomla2.5

I guess this is a stupid question but I have to ask it.

I work on an IT store and I work a lot with Joomla, so a friend of mine tried to do a website with joomla 2.5 on his own, and spent the money on a server that does not have the required MySQL version for joomla2.5 then he came to ask me what he could do now, I told him to rent another server but he asked me if I can do any thing to the database in a way that it still works with joomla 2.5 on a server with MySQL 4.x.x.

I guess that all he can do is have another server with the database and his site connects with it(probably will slowdown the site performance)
or he rents another server that have all the requirements.

but I am not entirely sure if there is some kind of ninja trick that enables him to use joomla2.5 with a MySQL 4.x.x Server.

thanks in advance;
Fernando Andrade

Comment: probably not. mysql 5 is very different from 4, and if joomla uses any of the new v5 features, there'll be NO way to fake it into using v4.

Comment: that is actually what I told him but he was so desperate that I had to ask, hoping that I was wrong... after all this is the internet and I might find someone smarter than me(not that it would be a difficult task lol)

Comment: a hosting co which is offering up mysql4 really needs to get its act together...

Comment: I know and I am guessing that even PHP is outdated, my friend told me that the answer that the company gave was that that server is not getting any updates soon and that they are thinking in getting a new one but they don't know when... lol we have brilliant people in Portugal but we also get this -.-'